# Can I store a relational table in memory and query it in node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

when a node js program starts, i will read data from a table and store it in nodejs global memory.Once this is loaded, in the program, when traffic comes, select a row from the loaded table based on some parameters.

Comment: That's entirely possible theoretically, but I'd question why you're doing it. If you're just looking for performance, look into using something like redis for storing your data.

Comment: The table is stored in mysql ,quering it on every request will not be feasible.

Comment: @NavedMir What makes you say that? Querying a database on every page load is perfectly fine for 99% of websites on the internet today. And for the 1% with considerably higher load, most of them place a simple in-memory cache in front of it.

Comment: @ColinM it is rtb bidder program.It gets 100-1000 request per second.We cant query db for every request.Normally we use memcache which is not possible in this case

Comment: 1000 requests per second is really not as much as it sounds, and well within the parameters of a properly equipped and tuned database. I would actually try it first and come back if ti becomes a problem. Make sure you index things correctly.

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Lite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/) is an in-process database which can write either to a disk file or to memory.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');


let db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.');
});
```

Now you can serialize queries and use it as an in-memory database.